# How do I set a default value on a semantic ui react dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I have a `Semantic UI React Dropdown Form.Field` I am trying to set a default value of `English` how can I do this?

```
<Form.Field
   name="languageSkills"
   label=""
   placeholder="Language"
   value={this.state.reviewerSearch.languageSkills['English']}
   onChange={this.handleSearchFilterChange}
   category={'languages'}
   control={LookupDropdown}
   fluid
   multiple
   search
   selection
/>
```

Comment: can you please change `value` to `defaultValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for defaultValue,

```
<Form.Field
   name="languageSkills"
   label=""
   placeholder="Language"
   defaultValue={this.state.reviewerSearch.languageSkills['English']}
   onChange={this.handleSearchFilterChange}
   category={'languages'}
   control={LookupDropdown}
   fluid
   multiple
   search
   selection
/>
```